# UITableView cell autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout, swift4

I have two issues but hoping that they're linked!  I have the following UITableView template that i am trying to get setup:-

[image: App Layout]

- White area is the table background
- Purple is the category title (this can use as little or as much as the purple area)
- Red is a View All button that should be pinned to the right.
- Green is a horizontal UICollectionView but each table row can have a different collection view height (notice the difference between row 1 and 2; row 3 is cut-off at the bottom of the screen)
- The pink line is a row separator

So far i have created the following class

```
import UIKit

class CategoryRowCell: UITableViewCell {
    let gradient = GradientView()
    let titleLbl = UILabel()
    let viewAllBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setupCategoryViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        titleLbl.text = ""
        viewAllBtn.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
        collectionView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
    }

    func setupCategoryViews() {
        //Title
        titleLbl.textColor = .white
        titleLbl.numberOfLines = 1
        titleLbl.textAlignment = .left
        titleLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(titleLbl)

        //View All
        viewAllBtn.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
        viewAllBtn.setTitle("View All", for: .normal)
        viewAllBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(viewAllBtn)

        //Collection View
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.bounces = false
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(collectionView)


        let titleConstraints = [
            titleLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
            titleLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            titleLbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewAllBtn.leadingAnchor)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(titleConstraints)

        let viewAllBtnConstraints = [
            viewAllBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLbl.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            viewAllBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLbl.centerYAnchor)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(viewAllBtnConstraints)

        let collectionViewConstraints = [
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(collectionViewConstraints)
    }

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: UICollectionViewDelegate & UICollectionViewDataSource>(_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {
        collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.tag = row
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Ok, so the issues i have are:-

The red view all area is not pinned to the right of the screen.  Instead it is pinned to the right edge of the purple view (with no gap).  I am expecting the purple text area to be that width (without specifying a width or percentage) even when the text length is short.

Whatever i do to try and get this working i get constraint conflicts and the logs are not very clear to me.

The second issue (well, not so much an issue) was to know if there is anything in particular i may need to consider or have to do in order for the table view and collection view to adjust their heights according to its content!?  You will see at the moment i am using a fixed height constraint which is not what want.

```
collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
```

Here is an example of what i am currently seeing
[image: WrongLayout]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.  I had to change the titleConstraints and viewAllBtnConstraints to the following

```
    let titleConstraints = [
        titleLbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
        titleLbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(titleConstraints)

    let viewAllBtnConstraints = [
        viewAllBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLbl.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
        viewAllBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        viewAllBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLbl.centerYAnchor)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(viewAllBtnConstraints)
```